# How to access the value of x after onclick is run

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Safe extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         userInput: "",
         password: 1234
      }
   }

   keyClicked = (evt) => {
      // HERE!!
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className="safe">
            <div className="display">{this.state.userInput}</div>
            <div className="keypad">
               {Array.from({length: 9}, (x, key) => <button className="key" key={key++} onClick={this.keyClicked}>{key++}</button>)}
            </div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

I am attempting to make a "safe" with a number pad. In order to open the safe, the user must enter a specific code in order to "open it".

Currently, I am working on showing what the user has input through the number pad onto the display. However, I am unsure on how to get what number the user has inputted through the number pad. I have put a comment saying "HERE!!" to show where I want to access the inputted number.

I have attempted to use `evt.target.value` but when I try to `console.log()` the `evt`, it shows up as an empty string.

Any help is appreciated as I'm new to React!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for this case is better to use `map()`. And declare the array beforehand. This way it's possible to pass the number clicked as an argument to the click handler.

**Try the following:**

```
export default class Safe extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userInput: "",
      password: 1234
    };
  }

  numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  handleClick = (n) => {
    console.log(n)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="safe">
        <div className="display">{this.state.userInput}</div>
        <div className="keypad">
          {this.numbers.map((number, i) => {
            return (
              <button
                className="key"
                key={i}
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(number)}
              >
                {number}
              </button>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can get this by this way

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Safe extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         userInput: "",
         password: 1234
      }
   }

   keyClicked = (evt) => {
     console.log(evt)
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className="safe">
            <div className="display">{this.state.userInput}</div>
            <div className="keypad">
               {Array.from({length: 9}, (x, key) => <button className="key" key={key++} onClick={()=>this.keyClicked(key++)}>{key++}</button>)}
            </div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to get the number inputted by the user. E.g. if the user clicked 2, I would like to log the number which the user clicked which was 2

Comment: Yea i updated the code now you can check it

Comment: If you have any query you can ask